# Process Workflow: Given key is not present in the dictionary in UiPath

Tags: workflow, uipath

I am doing **UiPath** level-3 Assignment 1. I have made all the workflows using **Ui Studio** and I am stuck in the process workflow. While I run the WFs, it says

> Process WF: Given dictionary is not present.

I checked all the values and arguments and they seem correct too.

Also when I run the Process WF separately, it gets stuck for each loop and say

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Could someone help resolving these issues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you renamed the Process Workflow? Are the names on Project Folder and in Invoked Workflow the same? Please share some screenshots.

Comment: No I didn't change the names.

Comment: I cant upload the screenshots as it is not allowing me to.

Comment: Can you check that all your arguments and variables are not missing any values?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing null value/trying to get value from dictionary using the key which doesn't exist. Please also remember that before using dictionary you have to create it.

It will be easier to help if you can provide status window logs at least.

Answer (score 0):

> As you said - I checked all the values and arguments and they seem
>   correct too.

So just check for spaces in your config file from where you are reading data and putting them in Dictionary.

Second Possibility

which seems to me is just check your arguments via which you are passing your configuration dictionary to your workflow. are you passing it from main workflow to your child workflows.
just double check your arguments.

Regards..!!

Aksh